# Some API or any helpful tool/repo for doing a text summary

Tags: javascript, api, nlp

So I wanted to start a new project of a text summarizer tool (a website). So far I found a free API for summarizing English text (smmry.com), but for other languages I want to include (French and Arabic), I couldn't find any free APIs. Can anyone suggest some reliable tools or resources so I can include these languages, too (free for sure)?

I am trying to avoid just simply translating the text to English and then summarizing it. That will be slightly robotic.

Comment: free = [tag:gratis] or [tag:open-source]?

Answer (score 0):

{1} indicates that GPT-3 is a good text summarizer. So you can use [GPT-J](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gptj), the open-source but less   effective version of GPT-2.

---

References:

- {1} Goyal, Tanya, Junyi Jessy Li, and Greg Durrett. "[News Summarization and Evaluation in the Era of GPT-3.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.12356.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2209.12356 (2022).